# unable to understand code/functions in header.php in Twenty Fourteen theme in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to wordpress. i am facing problem to understand codes written in twenty fourteen theme in wordpress . In staring of body of header.php there is some piece of code which i am not able to understand, like what they do

```
<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
<div id="site-header">
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
        <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
    </a>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

please someone help me to understand what this piece of code do

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>`

It is for if you set a Banner Image for you theme you can change by Customize theme and change or remove as shown in Image below through Admin Panel go to Appearance > customize then it will lead you to the page of customization as shown in Image there you will find Header Image.

[image]

```
<div id="site-header">
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
   <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">
  </a>
</div>
```

so Here in this code If the header Image found it will set in the `<img>` automatically it's `alt` will be set as site **NAME** and height or width will be set as theme defauld CSS. and the `<a>` before `<img>` is for leading link for HOME PAGE.

Comment: so this is not a mandatory code which i need to add in my custom page ?

Comment: Can you please explain how you want to build your custom pages? because WordPress is easy to Customize so that I can help you for further.

Comment: as of now i am learning how to develop custom page/website in  wordpress.

Comment: If you want to change in pages you don't need to edit `header.php` you must take a look at `page.php` or `single.php` it is for pages and posts you create in wordpress. or If you want to edit the Main (Home) page you should take a look at `index.php`

Comment: sir do we need to follow wordpress's classes in html codes or we can use class as per our convenience

Comment: You can put your own classes also as html structure you want to develop views in your site. it's not a mandatory to follow wordpress's classes but It is better to get it as it is and put your view html as you need if you want to make custom pages you can try to create a template file also [Template Link](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) You can see in this link. ( _You should upvote the answer if you get result what you want._)

Comment: could you please tell me what is best approach to develop a website with the help of custom pages in wordpress. (sir , i already upvoted your answere )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116252/discussion-between-arpit-gupta-and-dharit-soni).